# SyntaxHighlighter Evolved: PHP Versions >7.0 don’t work properly

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax-highlighting, syntaxhighlighter

I tried PHP 7.1, 7.2 and 7.3 but the code was displayed raw. When I went back to 7.0 it worked as it should. Problem is that I have to pay huge amounts for extended support of 7.0.

I know that the developer of SyntaxHighlighter Evolved tragically died of cancer but perhaps somebody can help with a workaround?

In case that this may help, here is the link to my blog: http://blog.ephorie.de

Full disclosure: I posted this question in the official support forum weeks ago but got no reaction: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/php-version-7-0-dont-work/

Hopefully somebody here can help... Thank you!

Comment: I'm using that plugin on my site with PHP 7.2.17 and it works as it should.

Comment: @cabrerahector: Strange... could you give me the link to your site? Thank you

Comment: If you need to see a live example, here: [How to create a simple image slider with vanilla JavaScript](https://cabrerahector.com/javascript/how-to-make-an-image-slider-with-vanilla-javascript-from-scratch/). I used the plugin to show the actual code needed to complete the tutorial.

Comment: @cabrerahector: That is really strange... I looked at the source code... it is the exact same version and same syntax as far as I can tell... in case you want to have a look: my blog is at http://blog.ephorie.de

Comment: I'm guessing you're still using PHP 7.0 as the code I'm seeing on [this post](http://blog.ephorie.de/check-machin-like-formulae-with-arbitrary-precision-arithmetic) seems fine. You'll need to upgrade to PHP 7.2/7.3 so the problem manifests itself and we can help you debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved with version 3.5.5.